Minimal number of binary operators to generate an arbitrary truth table
Considering: $$G(X,A,B)=(X∧A)∨(¬X∧B)$$
For all boolean unary operator $F(X)$, there exists a unique pair of $A,B$ so that $G(X,A,B)=F(X)$ for all $X$. That is, by assigning correct $A,B$, function $G$ can generate any unary boolean operator. There exists some other constructions of $G$ with less binary operators ($⊕$ means xor):
$$G(X,A,B)=(X∧A)⊕B$$ $$G(X,A,B)=(X∨A)⊕B$$
Now consider an arbitrary binary operator $F(X,Y)$ and function $G(X,Y,A,B,C,D)$, a trivial construction might be:
$$G(X,Y,A,B,C,D)=(X∧Y∧A)∨(¬X∧Y∧B)∨(X∧¬Y∧C)∨(¬X∧¬Y∧D)$$
Again, by changing value of $A,B,C,D$, function $G$ can generate all possible binary operator $F$. But this construction is computationally expensive.
My question is:

Is there a construction of $G(X,Y,A,B,C,D)$ requiring only $5$ binary operators to connect these operands? If not, what is the min number of binary operators required? (all 16 binary operators are useable)
For $F(X_1,X_2 ... X_i)$, $G(X_1 ... X_i,A_1 ... A_{2^i})$, how to find a construction of $G$ with min number of binary operators?


"Mock" means to make fun of. I suspect you meant to write "make'. Please edit your question to make it make sense.

@Rob Arthan Indeed verb "to mock" has to be repaced by another one ; Instead of "to make", I would advise "to retrieve"

Ok I will change it to "retrieve". Sorry for the confusion.

"Retrieve" sounds weird in this context ("retrieve" means to find something you have lost): if you don't like "make", I'd say "generate". More importantly, what binary operators are you allowing? You clearly need to take into account all 6 variables, so it looks highly unlikely that 5 binary operators would do as each variable would have to appear exactly once.

Sure I'll change it to "generate". I am allowing all 16 binary operators. It will be better if the operators are commutative.

Of course, you can gain 2 operators using factorisation ; for example the 2 last factors : $(X∧¬Y∧C)∨(¬X∧¬Y∧D)$ can be factored into $¬Y∧((X∧C)∨(¬X∧D))$. Can you do more ? I don't know...
